# Flutter can't add drawer

Tags: flutter

I am finding it difficult to add a drawer in the latest version of flutter. My code looks like this

```
class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomeScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: buildAppbar(),
      body: const Body(),
      drawer: DrawerSlide(),
    ); 
  }

  AppBar buildAppbar() {
    return AppBar(
      elevation: 3,
      leading: GestureDetector(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
          child: SvgPicture.asset('assets/icons/menu.svg', width: 10, height: 10, fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,),
        ),
        onTap: () => Scaffold.of(context).openDrawer(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

There is an error shown in Scaffold.of(context).openDrawe() that the context is not defined. It was working till I updated my flutter but in new flutter I think it is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `buildAppbar` method requires `context` as a positional argument :

```
AppBar buildAppbar(BuildContext context) {
    return AppBar(
      elevation: 3,
      leading: GestureDetector(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
          child: SvgPicture.asset('assets/icons/menu.svg', width: 10, height: 10, fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,),
        ),
        onTap: () => Scaffold.of(context).openDrawer(),
      ),
    );
  }
```

use it like :

```
return Scaffold(
      appBar: buildAppbar(context),
      body: const Body(),
      drawer: DrawerSlide(),
    );
```